# How do the pairs complex conjugate embeddings extend in the semi-direct product of Galois groups?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a finite Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is not totally real and let $(\sigma_1, \overline{\sigma_1}), \ldots, (\sigma_l, \overline{\sigma_l})$ be the pairs of complex conjugate embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$. Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension such that $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois and 
$$Gal(L/\mathbb{Q}) \cong Gal(L/K) \rtimes Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}),$$
where $\rtimes$ stands for semi-direct product.

Let the $g_1, g_2, \ldots, g_n$ be the elements of $Gal(L/K)$.

Under the above conditions, I would like to know if the pairs of complex conjugate embeddings of $L$ into $\mathbb{C}$ are given by $(g_j\sigma_i, g_j\overline{\sigma_i})$ (with $1 \leq j \leq n$, $1\leq i \leq l$). If this is true, what would be a way to prove it? If the statement does not hold, can we say anything about how the complex conjugate pairs are related via the semidirect product?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not necessarily. Consider $ K = \mathbf Q(\zeta_3) $, $ L = \mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta_3) $. We have that $ \textrm{Gal}(L/\mathbf Q) \cong S_3 $, which is the semidirect product of $ C_3 $ and $ C_2 $, so the desired condition is satisfied. Now, let $ \sigma $ be a $ 3 $-cycle and $ \tau $ be complex conjugation. The embeddings given by $ \sigma \tau $ and $ \sigma \bar{\tau} = \sigma $ are not conjugate: we have

$$ \sigma \tau (\sqrt[3]{2}) = \zeta_3 \sqrt[3]{2} $$
$$ \sigma(\sqrt[3]{2}) = \zeta_3 \sqrt[3]{2} $$

whereas $ \bar{\sigma}(\sqrt[3]{2}) = \tau \sigma(\sqrt[3]{2}) = \zeta_3^2 \sqrt[3]{2} $. Essentially, the desired condition breaks down because $ S_3 $ is not abelian.

However, it is obviously true that complex conjugate embeddings are given by $ (\sigma_i g_j, \bar{\sigma_i} g_j) $, since function composition is associative.

Comment: Thank you very much, very simple and clear counter-example. I am not 100% sure I understood the last part of your answer, do you mean that if we swapped the order of factors the condition would be satisfied?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: This works whenever we have a direct product, since the order of the factors doesn't matter, but I do not think it works for a general semi-direct product, does it?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you. Last thing: for the similar reasons like those you mentioned at the end of your question, is it though true that the embeddings are $g_j\sigma_i$ and their conjugates $g_j\overline{\sigma_i}$, but not necessarily paired as in my question?

Comment: No - this example should show you that pretty clearly, since there is only one way to pair up elements of a group of order 2, and it does not work...